# Why does running this phar file spurios characters?

Tags: php, phar

I am trying to run the [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) on my OSX terminal. Running it on the terminal causes the following output:

[image: Strange output on running phar file]

PHP Version:

```
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Jan  7 2015 10:59:34) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Why could this be happening?

Comment: A screenshot by itself isn't useful debugging information. PHP version, a hexdump, and environment information, etc. are perhaps.

Comment: Something similar happens when you run the phar version of PHPUnit 4 using PHP 5.3. I couldn't find the reason but I found a fix: I upgraded my PHP to 5.4